# Deploy Android app apk as an Internal app in Airwatch

Tags: android, mdm, airwatch

I am trying to deploy an apk app as an Internal App in Airwatch.
I am going to Workspace One UEM console -> Resources -> Apps -> Native -> Add -> 'Application file' and add the apk from local file.
The application is added and I assign an assignment group with the relevant groups of device.
Yet even that relevant group was assigned - I don't see the devices under the app and therefore the application is not pushed:
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpUTl.png)
Am I doing something wrong? What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: I believe you should ask this question in this app's forum or support rather than here

Comment: Thanks Dan. I need to understand something' may be you know. Can I deploy every apk as an Internal App? Do I need the developer details for that? (I download it from the Google Play and just tried to upload the apk).

Comment: Sorry, but my knowledge with MDMs is very little so I'm afraid I'm unable to help out here

Answer (score 1):

My answer is really late, you may have already fixed this, but for everyone else that may come across this post...

Are they enrolled in COPE, COBO or Work Profile? For internal apps there is an issue for COPE and Work Profile management since the internal apps won't work on them if you upload them from there.

Our solution was to upload it from the Google iframe as a public-private app. In airwatch you need to access the Public page and add a new app. Once you've opened the Google iframe you must access the private apps setting (which you can find on the menu on the left with a lock icon) and upload it from there. Once you upload it, you can assign it and the app will show up as if it was a public playstore app.

But there is an important thing to consider, the ID of the app must be unique, once it's used and passed the google iframe you won't be able to use it for any other client.